# Resize childcontrols in a panel automatically in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

i have a question about automatically resizing childcontrols of a panel if the panel change the width or the height. I use Asp.net (vb.net). Is there an extender or a property of the panel which allows this?
Or is there another panel which has the possiblity to auto resize their controls?

Or a javascript (jquery) plugin which allows resizing. I know the jquery.ui resiziable plugin, but i don't know if the plugin allows me to resize the childrencontrols when i change the size of the main panel with textboxes for example.

So i want to set the width for my button to 100px and add it to my panel like

```
main_panel.controls.add(btn)
```

On my testpage i have two textboxes which allows me to resize the panel, the main panel with the button as his childrencontrol and another button for submiting the panelresizing.

i hope anyone understand me, my english is waste(:

Answer (score 2):

There multiple solutions to your problem depending on your knowledge/requirements.

1. you can set a fixed size in when you add the controls to the panel
   (with .NET)
2. you can set up flexible rules with css which automatically make the controls inside the div or even set them all the same fixed size the div will scale
3. you can do this with script as well, target all the elements and make them the same size

Depending on your need (eg does the user do the resizing? or is it window resizing?) I find it the easiest to set up solution 2 and then add an event listener when needed. For instance when the project requires re-sizing when the user sizes his browser window. 
Just be careful though the window resize event is very "heavy" and gets triggered a lot so use it only when absolutely needed

English is not my native tongue as well so I hope I understood your question; if not just shoot :)

*(try to avoid option 1, it is the least flexible and scalable)*